Encrypt body request using AES algorithm
I'm having trouble making a request to an API using C#, basically I need to send a POST request to a specific endpoint, and the body of the request needs to be encrypted using AES algorithm in the browser, they use CryptoJS.AES library for encryption the body request, the problem is, I can't get the encryption to work properly in C#. It doesn't work but when I use the encryption that was generated by the frontend as my payload within the request (in C# code) everything works fine.
Encryption key is: abcdefghijuklmno0123456789012345
The request I'm trying to get is a POST to this endpoint: https://demo4.sasradius.com/admin/api/index.php/api/login
the data to encrypt is username and password
ex : { "username":"admin",   "admin":"admin" }
The final request body should look something like this: { payload: encrypted_data_here }
The frontend: https://demo4.sasradius.com/
login creds: username = admin, password = admin
inspect the network on login to get an idea of the encrypted payload
hint: all encryption generated on login starts with "Salted__"  as base64 text.

No headless browser or something similar, I would make the request from my code (C#) like in this example:

  // Encrypt data (request body)
  var requestData = new { username = "admin", password = "admin" };
  var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
  var key = "abcdefghijuklmno0123456789012345";
  var encryptedPayload = await Encrypt(requestBody, key); // I would create this method ?
  
  // request
  var url = "https://demo4.sasradius.com/admin/api/index.php/api/login";
  var payload = new { payload = encryptedPayload };
  var payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
  using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(payloadJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

I'm trying to encrypt the body request using AES algorithm with salted prefix
Like the encryption generated by CryptoJS library
my code to encrypt the body (AES encryption method):
btw I'm not that good at encryption, so I get some help from ChatGPT to implement the method
    public static string Encrypt(string form, string key)
    {
        byte[] salt = GenerateRandomBytes(8);
        using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var keyDerivation = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt, 1000);
        aes.Key = keyDerivation.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
        aes.IV = keyDerivation.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

        using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] saltedPrefix = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Salted__");
        msEncrypt.Write(saltedPrefix, 0, saltedPrefix.Length);
        msEncrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);
            swEncrypt.Write(form);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
    }

the server response is: InternalServerError
which means that the encryption is not valid or not correct
btw I tried to use the same payload (encryption generated by CryptoJs) from the frontend by inspect network, works just fine. so that means the issue with the encryption

Post the CryptoJS code you want to port. The prefix Salted__ indicates that the built-in key derivation of CryptoJS is used (EVP_BytesToKey()). The result is (commonly) returned in the Base64 encoded OpenSSL format (Salted__ + 8 bytes salt + ciphertext). This must be taken into account in the C# code.

they set no parameters or options for AES algorithm so i didn't get the correct parameters like IV, KeySize/BlockSize etc...
This code is from frontend (inspect)
let t = {"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(t),"abcdefghijuklmno0123456789012345").toString()

So what exactly is the problem? Is the server replying back with an error? If so, what's the error? You are telling us something is wrong without giving any details about the actual error.

sorry, the frontend works fine, I mean the payload generated by cryptoJs is works just fine and logged in successfully, the issue with the generated encryption by my c# code
which i will provide in my question.
the error is caused by that the encryption is not correct so the backend cant decrypt my request body which contains the credentials.

And how do you know the backend cannot decrypt it? Is it generating an error? What's the error? Tell us what the server is saying, not what you think is the problem.

i did edit the question.
i'm pretty sure the the encryption was not correct (server can't decrypt) because i tried to usethe encryption generated by CryptoJs with the correct credentials and it works fine when i sent the request from my c# code ( instead of using the encryption generated by c# i used the one generated by CryptoJS)

just FYI, CryptoJS has been discontinued and you can use internal crypto modules that comes with browser. You can still use AES encryption using a key with internal crypto module.

The frontend is a dashboard for a public API, and I'm currently working on project that will pull some data from the API , The issue is that each request need to be encrypted using AES, I mentioned the Frontend URL in my question was just to give an idea of how the request is encrypted, and how it works fine.
but actually my task is to login (to the API), encrypt the body request, get the data
my issue is : request body encryption (AES encryption which it doesn't work with C#)

I voted to close this question. I found another question with an answer that I tested and was able to get it to log in. See the Protection class provided in there. What you are calling an encryption key is actually a passphrase.

You are using the wrong key derivation in the C# code. Rfc2898DeriveBytes() is PBKDF2 and not EVP_BytesToKey(). So you need a C# implementation for the latter (BouncyCastle or one from the web). As EVP_BytesToKey() parameters MD5 as digest and an iteration count of 1 are to be applied.

Thank you very much. now it's running well
close the question
